# Disappearing DOM element does not register click event

Tags: reactjs, mouseevent, mouselistener

I'm constructing an input field in React that looks like so:

[image: Search box]

When the 'x' is clicked (`StyledCloseCircle`), the text will be cleared, and the 'x' symbol should disappear. The 'x' symbol is currently shown with javascript when the input field is focused,

```
export const Search = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [isFocused, setFocus] = useState(false);
  const [isHovered, setHover] = useState(false);

  return (
    <InputContainer
      onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
    >
      <StyledInput
        onFocus={() => setFocus(true)}
        onBlur={() => setFocus(false)}
        isHovered={isHovered}
        ref={ref}
        {...props}
      />
      {isFocused && !props.value && (
        <StyledMagnifyingGlass
          isHovered={isHovered}
          isFocused={isFocused}
          onClick={props.onSearch}
        />
      )}
      {isFocused && props.value && (
        <StyledCloseCircle onClick={() => console.log("THIS DOES NOT FIRE")} />
      )}
      {!isFocused && (
        <StyledMagnifyingGlass
          isHovered={isHovered}
          isFocused={isFocused}
          onClick={props.onSearch}
        />
      )}
    </InputContainer>
  );
});
```

The issue is that when the 'x' is clicked, the input looses focus, which causes the 'x' to be removed on the next render, and does not register the `click` event. It does, however, trigger the `mousedown` event.

Therefore, my two questions are:

1. What is the order of operations when the 'x' is clicked, that leads it to registering `mousedown` but not `click`?
2. How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a separate state to control where to show/hide the Clear button. Show it `onFocus` even as you do now but hide it if user clicks outside of the input container or if clicks on the Clear button. You can additionally hide it `onBlur` but with some timeout (500-1000ms) in case if user uses keyboard instead of a mouse.

This is a [CodeSnadbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/w6pyl35rml) of the code below:

```
function App() {
  const inputContainerRef = useRef();
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [showClear, setShowClear] = useState(false);

  const onFocus = useCallback(() => {
    setShowClear(true);
  }, []);

  const onClear = useCallback(() => {
    setValue("");
    setShowClear(false);
  }, []);

  const onOutsideClick = useCallback(e => {
    // hide Clear button only if clicked outside of the container
    if (!inputContainerRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
      setShowClear(false);
    }
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(
    () => {
      // set the listener only if we shown the Clear button and remove the listener once we hid it
      if (showClear) {
        document.addEventListener("click", onOutsideClick);
        return () => document.removeEventListener("click", onOutsideClick);
      }
    },
    [showClear] // re-invoke if the state changes
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="input-container" ref={inputContainerRef}>
        <input
          value={value}
          onChange={e => {
            setValue(e.target.value);
          }}
          className="input"
          type="tetxt"
          onFocus={onFocus}
        />
        {showClear && (
          <div className="clear" onClick={onClear}>
            X
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```